# How To Fix Django Heroku Requirements Deploy Failure

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a staging version of my Django app to Heroku, and I'm receiving an error. The reason I mention that it's a staging app is that my production app is running fine, but I think maybe some packages updated since I set it up?

The error is referencing `python-http-client==3.1.0` which I don't understand, since my requirements.txt has `python-http-client==3.2.1`

I think I used Pipenv originally a long time ago but ended up switching back to not using it, and to be honest I'm a bit confused about it.

I don't currently have a pipfile or pipfile.lock, yet Heroku says ***Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock*** during deployment, so I'm at a loss. Here is the error:

```
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.5
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (d4a1e0)…
remote:        An error occurred while installing python-http-client==3.1.0! Will try again.
remote:        Installing initially–failed dependencies…
remote:        Collecting python-http-client==3.1.0
remote:          Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/5c/9e0cde562757bdb385a3644235e7c4da6f76c8a43d573eb76384ef461d40/python_http_client-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
remote:
remote:        THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM Pipfile.lock!. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
remote:            python-http-client==3.1.0 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5c/5c/9e0cde562757bdb385a3644235e7c4da6f76c8a43d573eb76384ef461d40/python_http_client-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=84267d8dcb7bcdf4c5cef321a533cc584c5b52159d4a4d3d4139bfed347b8006 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-6k8jlqu1-requirements/pipenv-73gxws2n-requirement.txt (line 1)):
remote:                Expected sha256 7e430f4b9dd2b621b0051f6a362f103447ea8e267594c602a5c502a0c694ee38
remote:                     Got        84267d8dcb7bcdf4c5cef321a533cc584c5b52159d4a4d3d4139bfed347b8006
```

It seems like somehow I need to tell heroku to not use the pipfile.lock, but I don't know where it's getting that since it's not in my code.

Any help much appreciated. This stuff is hard to troubleshoot!

If there's any important info I did not include, please let me know.

Comment: "It seems like somehow I need to tell heroku to not use the pipfile.lock"—no, you should _update_ your `Pipfile.lock`. How are you installing and updating libraries? Do you manually edit `Pipfile` or do you run `pipenv install...`?

Comment: @Chris I would run pip install X. I don't use pipenv anymore, so that was confusing things. I found a solution in a github thread (explained in edit). Thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: [Please don't edit a solution into your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, add an answer below and then accept it. [Self-answers are encouraged here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).